# Slow performance using /dev/random in docker desktop WSL2

Tags: linux, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, docker-desktop

**Context**:

I have a JAVA Web Application running on a **Docker Linux container**. The application uses a FIPS 3RD party library to do some cryptographic operations. Such library makes heavy use of **/dev/random** when it's deployed in Linux environments. I can neither modify the library nor replace it.

To develop/test the application, I use **Docker Desktop for Windows**. If I deploy the application using the **WSL1** engine, the application runs smoothly. However, if I instruct Docker Desktop to use the **WSL2 engine**, the application starts lagging during cryptographic operations ...

**Question**:

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Before** applying any of these solutions, check if missing of entropy is your real problem ... To do that execute these commands (in your docker host and in your container):

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
```

It should return a number greater that `1000` ...

```
dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/null bs=1024 count=1 iflag=fullblock
```

It should return fast! (Sources: [haveged](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Haveged) and [rng-tools](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Rng-tools))

**Solutions:**

**For Windows Users** (those of you that run DockerDestop for Windows):

1. Keep using the WSL1 engine with Docker Desktop.
2. If the previous solution is not possible, execute [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34396278/1474069):

> docker pull harbur/haveged

> docker run --privileged -d harbur/haveged

**Explanation**: This will run a docker container that executes the haveged daemon/process as CMD. Such process, plus  `--privileged` flag, will feed your **host** `/dev/random` with entropy, avoiding blocking issues.

**For Linux users** (those running Linux as docker host):

1. Map as a volume/mount-point your host's `/dev/urandom` to your container's `/dev/random`. This will trick your container, and when it use `/dev/random`, it will be using your host's `/dev/urandom`, which never blocks by design. People may [argue](https://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/) that's insecure, but that is out the scope of this question.
2. Install in your **docker host**, a software that increments the entropy pool, like [haveged](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Haveged) or [rng-tools](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Rng-tools) (if you have a hardware TRNG)

**Final thoughts and conclusions:**

1. `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` in a docker container point to `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` of the docker host. I don't have any documentation that backups this, except these: [Missing Entropy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30577161/1474069) and [How docker handles /dev/(u)random request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52699235/1474069) ... and the experimental fact that if I access the WSL2 docker-desktop-distro (using `wsl -d docker-desktop`) and I execute the `dd` command described previously, I can see how the entropy is reduced both in the host and the container (and viceversa) ... This is why using solutions, like deploying the haveged container or installing haveged in the docker host, work.
2. According to [haveged](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Haveged) link, such software is deprecated because its logic is now included in linux kernels v5.6 ... This could mean that if your docker host is running a Linux Kernel equals or greater to the version 5.6, you won't need to do anything of this because `/dev/random` will never block.
3. I tried to install haveged in the WSL2 docker distro (`docker-desktop`), but such distro does not allow you to execute `apt-get` ...